# Issue with the spring security tutorial on spring.io

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to run the [spring security application](https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/) on the official website. When I try to access the context root I get the user authentication prompt even though `.antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()` allows all access to `/home` and `/`. Also the password is being set in the application in the following code

```
@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
}
```

However I still get the `Using default security password` message in the logs with the password mentioned. Please could you help.

**Edit:**

I had made a mistake in the code, I forgot to annotate the `WebSecurityConfig` class with `@Configuration` and `@EnableWebSecurity` annotations.

Answer (score 1):

The `password` which you find from log is from `basic auth` which is by default enabled, you can do `httpBasic().disabled()` to disable it, then you will not see the default password any more.

**Update**
I saw you are using `spring-boot`, which makes live much easier, try add this property: `security.basic.enabled=false`, it should help you to disable it..

Comment: Please could you guide me where to make the changes. I tried to add `.httpBasic().disable()` but it did not work